# ¿Cómo sumar dos objetos java?

Tags: java

Tengo un ejercicio de programación en el que tengo que sumar dos objetos "Tiempo" pero no sé como hacerlo.

Así es el UML:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y debo de decidir los métodos estáticos.

```
package tempo;

public class Temps {
private int hores;
private int minuts;
private int segons;

public Temps(){  //Sirve por si quiero llamar a esta y quiero inicializar en cero
    this.hores=0;
    this.minuts=0;
    this.segons=0;
}

public Temps(String valor){

    String matriz[] = valor.split(":");

    int hour = Integer.parseInt(matriz[0]);
    int minute = Integer.parseInt(matriz[1]);
    int second = Integer.parseInt(matriz[2]);

    this.hores=hour;
    this.minuts=minute;
    this.segons=second;

}

public Temps(int hores, int minuts, int segons){
    this.hores=hores;
    this.minuts=minuts;
    this.segons=segons;
}

public int[] geTemps(){
    int[] valors = new int[3];
    valors[0]=this.hores;
    valors[1]=this.minuts;
    valors[2]=this.segons;

    return valors;
}

public void SetValors(int hora, int minuts, int segons){ //por si quiero cambiar los valores
    this.hores=hora;
    this.minuts=minuts;
    this.segons=segons;
}

public Temps Suma(Temps param){

    return param;
}


}



}
```

Este es el main:

```
Temps a = new Temps(2,13,1);
Temps b = new Temps(12,413,121);            

a.Suma(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu método suma de tu clase Temps sería así , solo sumar los atributos

```
public Temps Suma(Temps param){
  this.hour = param.hour;
  this.minuts=param.minuts;
  this.segonds = param.segonds;
  return this;
}
   /* En el Main cuando haces a.Suma(b);  
  A Tendrá el valor después de la suma */
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que seria util modificar un poco el codigo para que desde que construyes el objeto Temps, lo hagas de forma correcta. En el ejemplo que pusiste, iniciaste la variable b asi:

```
Temps b = new Temps(12,413,121);
```

En el constructor asociado, deberias poner algo como:

```
Temps(int h, int m, int s) {
     m += s / 60;
     s %= 60;

     h += m / 60;
     m %= 60;

     h %= 24; // o % 12, depende con que sistema trabajes
     ......
}
```

Para el caso de la suma, creo que deberías retornar un objeto nuevo de la siguiente forma:

```
Temps Suma(Temps a) {
     return new Temps(this.hours + a.hours, this.minutes + a.minutes, this.seconds + a.seconds);
}
```

o algo similar, apoyandote en el constructor propuesto. Asi no vas a tener que sacrificar una de las dos variables que estas sumando. Espero que te sea util.

Answer (score 0):

Con el código que tienes, deberías sumar los valores uno por uno (Horas, minutos y segundos).

Yo haría el main así:

```
Temps a = new Temps(2,13,1);
Temps b = new Temps(12,413,121);   
int[] valorsA= new int[3]; 
int[] valorsB= new int[3]; 

valorsA= a.geTemps();
valorsB= b.geTemps();

int resultados[]= new int[3];
for(int i=0;i<a.lenght;i++){
    resultados[i]=valorsA[i]+valorsB[i];
}
for(int i=0;i<resultados.lenght;i++){
    System.out.println(resultados[i]);
}
```

Ahora mismo no puedo probarlo, espero no haber cometido errores, lo he escrito aquí mismo.

De querer hacerlo en la funcion `Suma`, sería igual, pero necesitarias pasar los valores (Horas, minutos y segundos) de un objeto Temp a otro.

Answer (score 0):

El metodo Suma, o suma debiera ser así:

```
import java.lang.Math
public Temps Suma(Temps sumando){
    int horaResultado = this.hores+sumando.getTemps()[0];
    int horaMinutes = this.minutes+sumando.getTemps()[1];
    int segundosResultado = this.segons+sumando.getTemps()[2];
    //convertimos todo a segundos, para después hacer la conversión y que la suma represente correctamente la suma de tiempo.
    int total = horaResultado*3600+horaMinutes*60+segundosResultado;
    Temps resultado = new Temps(total/3600, 
                            (total-Math.floor(total/3600))*60, 
                            (((total-Math.floor(total/3600))*60)-(Math.floor((total-Math.floor(total/3600))*60))*60)
                            ));
    return resultado;
}
```

El main debiera ser como lo mencionas.