# ¿Cómo puedo sumar dos variables tipo Object en Java?

Tags: java

Código en Java:

```
public Object sumar (Object a, Object b){return a+b;}
```

Y el error que me da es este:

> `Error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'`

Comment: Te recomiendo ver la respuesta a esta pregunta que es muy similar. http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26186/cómo-sumar-dos-objetos-java

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo sumar dos objetos java?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26186/c%c3%b3mo-sumar-dos-objetos-java)

Comment: No es duplicada ni la otra tiene respuesta válida aceptada.

Comment: Sin mas explicación, lo que pides no se puede, ni tiene mucho sentido. Pero tal vez si explicas mas en cuanto al porqué necesitas hacer esto, tal vez se te puede sugerir algo mas apropiado.

Comment: Independiente de lo que planificas, te recomiendo reconsiderar tu diseño. Un método como tu lo defines te causa puros problemas en Java. Si te molesta el nivel de estricto que es Java con tipos, quizás sería mejor de optar por otro lenguaje. No hay que hacer todo en Java :)

Comment: @Azteca no lo considero un duplicado. En esa pregunta se pide el diseño de un método `sumar` para una clase específica. Esta pregunta está asociada a la suma de `Object` en general y si es conviente generalizarla o no.

Answer (score 2):

En otros lenguajes, como C++ y C#, se puede definir la sobrecarga de los operadores matemáticos para las clases. En Java, **esto no se puede hacer**, descrito por el mismo James Gosling, creador de Java ([fuente](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm)):

> I left out operator overloading as a fairly personal choice because I had seen too many people abuse it in C++.

Traducido:

> Dejé la sobrecarga de operadores como una elección personal justa porque he visto a mucha gente abusando de ella en C++.

Por ende el mensaje de error `Error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'` cuando tienes el código `return a + b;`

---

Conociendo que tienes una restricción de diseño de parte del lenguaje. El código de tu método

```
public Object sumar (Object a, Object b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

No funciona. Solo va a funcionar si las variables son **explícitamente** de los siguientes tipos:

- `byte` (o el wrapper `Byte`)
- `short` (o el wrapper `Short`)
- `int` (o el wrapper `Integer`)
- `long` (o el wrapper `Long`)
- `float` (o el wrapper `Float`)
- `double` (o el wrapper `Double`)
- `char` (o el wrapper `Character`)
- `String`

Para los demás tipos, no se puede usar el operador `+` y debes decidir su propio método de suma.

Existen muchas combinaciones posibles para sobre escribir el método diseñado. Existen casos un poco complejos que pueden compilar y complicar la lectura del código. Por ejemplo:

```
String a = " hola ";
int b = 5;
System.out.println(a + b); // hola 5
System.out.println(b + a); //5 hola 
int c = 1;
System.out.println(a + b + c); // hola 51
System.out.println(b + a + c); //5 hola 1
System.out.println(a + (b + c)); // hola  6
```

Con todo esto en mente, en realidad y en opinión personal, te diría que lo que parece que intentas hacer no tiene mucho valor. Es más rápido escribir `a + b` donde tienes tipos conocidos de tus variables o inclusive definir un método `suma` dentro de cada clase específica donde lo vayas a usar (p.e. esta estrategia la usan las clases `BigInteger` y `BigDecimal`).

Answer (score 1):

No puedes usar el operador `+` con Objectos.

Si quieres usar el operador `+` tienes que ser con los siguientes tipos: int, float, double, etc.

`int sumar (int a, int b){return a+b;}` y también agregar de otro tipo de datos, `double sumar (double a, double b){return a+b;}`

Comment: La pregunta específicamente dice "Sumar Objetos", no int, double, float, etc.

Comment: No puedes usar el operador + con objetos tipo Object.

Comment: Yo sé, a lo que me refería es que la respuesta no va hacia la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Primero no ganas mucho con un método sumando objetos devolviendote un objeto, porque al fin terminas de nuevo con un objeto no especificado.

Una suma tiene sentido para un valor numérico, así tu método por lo menos podría garantizar de devolver un `Number`.

```
public Number sumarObjetos(Object o1, Object o2);
```

Un `Number` puede ser uno de los siguientes tipos:

- `BigDecimal`,`Double`, `Float`
- `BigInteger`,`Long`,`AtomicLong`,`Integer`,`AtomicInteger`,`Short`,`Byte`

Los representaciones de los primitivos (Double, Float, Long, Integer, Short y Byte) se pueden sumar usando el operador `+`, las otras clases no lo permiten.

Cuando se usa el operador `+` con tipos distintos en Java, el resultado es del tipo de más precisión. Por ejemplo:

```
Object o;
o = (Double)a + (Float)b; // o tiene tipo Double
o = (Short)a + (Float)b; // o tiene tipo Float
o = (Byte)a + (Long)b; // o tiene tipo Long
```

Entonces si quieres literalmente sumar usando el operador `+`, tienes que limitarte a los primitivos.

Que tipo para el resultado quieres eligir si uno o dos objetos no son primitivos?:

- ¿el tipo de o1?
- ¿el tipo de o2?
- ¿el tipo capaz de contener el resultado sin perdida de información?
- ¿un tipo predeterminado, como siempre `BigDecimal`?

Más encima tienes que decidir como quieres interpretar objetos que no son números.

- NaN siempre se interpretan como 0
- NaN se interpretan como `Double.valueOf(objeto.toString())`
- otras interpretación

Como ves, es muy difícil de darte una solución concreta sin definir más exacto el caso de uso que quieres implementar.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo puedo sumar dos variables tipo Object en Java?

La respuesta directa es que no se puede sumar 2 variables de tipo `Object` usando el operador `+`, porque en Java no se puede sobrecargar el uso de operadores.

Adicionalmente, aunque es posible implementar otras formas de sumar objetos usando métodos más tradicionales, para hacerlo se necesita entender más en cuanto al tipo de los objetos al *runtime*, cosa que no has explicado.  Porque si no se trata de tipos numéricos, entonces lo primero que debes hacer es definir cómo se define el concepto de una suma en el caso del tipo que tienes en mente.

Pero, en cualquier caso, persiste la pregunta de por qué deseas aplicar una suma a variables de tipo `Object` y no de algún tipo más específico. Porque al usar `Object`, significa que necesitas poder manejar una suma para cualquier tipo de objeto. Pero el concepto de suma no es aplicable a todos los tipos. Por esta razón, no creo que tenga sentido querer sumar 2 variables de tipo `Object`.

Comment: Creo que en lugar de decir que "no tiene sentido", la respuesta va por "en Java no se puede sobrecargar el uso de operadores en las clases" y luego brindar alternativas de solución.

Comment: @Luiggi: Gracias por el comentario. Usé lo que me recomendastes. Pero sigo de la opinión que no tiene mucho sentido querer sumar variables de tipo `Object` y espero haberlo explicado mejor.

Comment: Yo opino igual. Ante ello, he brindado una respuesta.

Comment: @Luiggi: Y me parece muy bien tu respuesta. Tocastes todos los puntos que tenía en mente, pero mucho mejor explicado :)

Answer (score -1):

Si se trata de un objeto, aunque éste pertenezca a la clase `Integer`  no puedes operar directamente sobre él, debes obtener el valor que hay dentro de la clase.

Ya que en la *caja* puede haber cualquier cosa necesitas saber lo que hay dentro de la caja.

Por ejemplo, puedes usar un método como este para operar sobre el Objeto:

```
//Cuando tengas tu objetos creados ^
//Se los pasas al método `sumarObjetos` el cual determina de qué tipo son

sumarObjetos (Object a, Object b);


public static Object sumarObjetos(Object o1, Object o2) throws Exception{

    if( o1 instanceof String || o2 instanceof String){
        return String.valueOf(o1) + String.valueOf(o2);
    }

    if( !(o1 instanceof Number) || !(o2 instanceof Number) ){
        throw new Exception("operandos inválidos para el operador matemático [+]");
    }

    if(o1 instanceof Double || o2 instanceof Double){
        return ((Number)o1).doubleValue() + ((Number)o2).doubleValue();
    }

    if(o1 instanceof Float || o2 instanceof Float){
        return ((Number)o1).floatValue() + ((Number)o2).floatValue();
    }

    if(o1 instanceof Long || o2 instanceof Long){
        return ((Number)o1).longValue() + ((Number)o2).longValue();
    }

    return ((Number)o1).intValue() + ((Number)o2).intValue();
}
```

[Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54427/29967) explica un poco la diferencia entre los objetos en sí y los tipos primitivos.

Comment: Te equivocas con lo que dices primero. `Integer a = 2; Long b = 2L; Long c = a+b;` es perfectamente valido y funciona.

Comment: Que yo sepa, también puedes hacer `String saludo = "hola " + "mundo"` y compila. No entiendo por qué el uso de `String#valueOf`.

Comment: @Luiggi: Creo que es en caso uno de los objetos es un `String`, pero el otro no.

Comment: @sstan pero según este código ambos objetos son de tipo `String`.

Comment: Veo que no han entendido lo que hace el método. Se trata de determinar lo que hay dentro de los dos objetos y entonces actuar en consecuencia. Creo que es la mejor manera de responder a la pregunta del OP. No dediqué más tiempo a mejorar el método porque como han dicho muchos la utilidad es mínima. La respuesta trata de presentar una posible solución al problema planteado.

Comment: @Luiggi: Nota que en todas las condiciones donde verifica el tipo del objeto, está usando un `OR`, no un `AND`.

Comment: @sstan Bueno, entonces me deja la salida a hacer maldades >=) como `sumarObjetos("hola", new Object());`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Quedarías atrapado en el if número 2. Ja ja Insisto: no entienden este método.

Comment: @A.Cedano en realidad, como es un `||` entraría en el primero ;)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza En el primero no hay ningún problema.

Comment: Te recomiendo ejecutar tu código antes de publicarlo. Si no tienes tu IDE favorito al alcance, puedes usar https://ideone.com/

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo , cubre varios casos :

```
public static Object sumar(Object o1,Object o2)
{
    if(o1 instanceof Integer && o2 instanceof Integer)
        return  ((int)o1) + ((int) o2) ;

    if(o1 instanceof Double && o2 instanceof Double)
        return  ((double)o1) + ((double) o2) ;

    if(o1 instanceof Float && o2 instanceof Float)
        return  ((float)o1) + ((float) o2) ;

    if(o1 instanceof Long && o2 instanceof Long)
        return  ((long)o1) + ((long) o2) ;

    if(o1 instanceof Short && o2 instanceof Short)
        return  ((short)o1) + ((short) o2) ;

    if(o1 instanceof Number && o2 instanceof Number)
        return (new Double(String.valueOf(o1))  +   (new Double(String.valueOf(o2)))   );

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Bueno, la solución no es complicada, pero si tienes que ir analizando todos los casos posibles dentro de tu método de suma. Te pongo una parte del código, tendrías que ir agregándole los demás tipos de datos, tanto para **a** como para **b** :

```
public class SumarNumeros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double a = 10;
        String b = "M";
        Object c = sumarNumeros(a, b);
        System.out.println("RESULTADO: " + c);
    }

    private static Object sumarNumeros(Object a, Object b) {
        Object resultado = 0;
        if(a instanceof Double) {
            if(b instanceof Double) {
                resultado = (double) a + (double) b;
            }
            else if(b instanceof Integer) {
                resultado = (double) a + (int) b;
            }
            else if(b instanceof String) {
                resultado = (double) a + (String) b;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Estaría bueno que la persona que votó con menos 1 diga el porque, no? Así todos aprendemos, ya que para mí, porque lo probé, es perfectamente válido